# Как сделать зеркало сайта?

Tags: администрирование, зеркало

Как лучше сделать зеркало сайта?

Гугл подсказал смотреть в сторону склейки папок на сервере, или в сторону редиректа.

Единственное, что хочу уточнить, нужно что бы url'ы внутренних страниц совпадали:

Например:

```
сайт.рф/page1.html - Зеркало 
site.ru/page1.html - Основа
```

Сайт на Joomla. Сам сайт и зеркало размещены на одной и той же площадке.

Comment: Параметры сервера какие? ПО какое используется?

Comment: PHP/5.2.17
nginx

Comment: Если что-то еще требуется пишите.

Comment: Rsync? я правда не знаю, у вас вроде url не только чтобы совпадали, но и переводились?